# Return Html page using RestController in Spring Boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, web, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to get the HTML page that I created. This is the structure of my project:

[image]

This is the "IndexController" class:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(path = "/webpage")
public class IndexController {

        @GetMapping(path = {"mainpage"})
        @ResponseBody
        public String index(){
            return "Index";
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/check")
        public String CheckDataset(@ModelAttribute CheckModel checkModel){
            System.out.println(checkModel);
            return null;
        }
    
    }
```

When I open the HTML webpage directly from intellij:

[image]

Is opening perfectly, but when I am trying to open the HTML from Spring Boot is returning just the "Index" String.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that your class IndexController shall not have `@RestController` if you need to show an HTML page. It shall only have `@Controller`.

In simple terms `@RestController = @Controller + @ResponseBody`

In your case, the `@RestController` annotation you used makes all the methods within it `@ResponseBody` by default, and you don't have to explicitly mention

`@ResponseBody` annotation doesn't show the view instead it sends a String response.

Steps to fix this issue:

1. Change `@RestController` annotation to `@Controller` in class level
2. Remove `@ResponseBody` from the method in which you're planning to show the HTML

So your code will be

```java
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(path = "/webpage")
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping(path = {"mainpage"})
    public String index(){
        return "Index";
    }

   //Other methods
    
}
```

Just make sure you have `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency in your POM.xml

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To return the HTML page (view), you have to use Spring MVC, i.e. `@Controller` instead of `@RestController` and return `ModelAndView` with `index` as a view name:

```java
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/webpage")
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping(path = {"mainpage"})
    public ModelAndView index() {
        final var modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is not working in my case, but thank you for your suggestion.